# Form validation unable to redirect page in PHP

Tags: php

i got some problem regarding form validation using PHP. I have done some research on google, the problem is I seem can't to redirect user after login using `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` in form action, it keep staying on index.php page instead going to other page.

Form

```
<?php
$usernameErr = $passwordErr = "";
$username = $password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

   if (empty($_POST["username"]))
     {$usernameErr = "Username is required.";}
   else
     {$username =($_POST["username"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["password"]))
     {$passwordErr = "Password is required.";}
   else
     {$password =($_POST["password"]);}
}
?>
<body>
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" id="username"><span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Or do I put it on wrong page? Should I put it on checklogin.php?

Comment: Where is your redirect script?

Comment: `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` _is_ the current page - so if you set that as the form action, why would you expect it to go anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Your not redirecting by `echo` statement.Use `header()` for redirection.like `header("Location:index.php");`

For details about header visit the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Correct way is `header("Location: index.php");` and then `die()` to stop script execution.

Comment: @ElonThan Agree to Location,but die() and exit() are not compulsory.

Comment: Do some tests. Script will be executing after setting header if you don't stop it. This function just sends header, nothing more. Script will stop soon after that (but not immediately). Also, depending on server configuration, can execute to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The form validation logic does belong to `checklogin.php`. You pointed your `<form>` to send its data to `checklogin.php`, but you are doing the actual validations in `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

ye. you need to put it in checklogin.php page.

and also make change like

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{

if (empty($_POST["username"]))
 {
    echo $usernameErr = "Username is required.";}

  elseif (empty($_POST["password"]))
  {
   echo $passwordErr = "Password is required.";}
  else
  {
     echo $password =$_POST["password"];
   echo  $username =$_POST["username"];}
}
?>
```

Comment: i have made the little change in my code. so update it in your file

Comment: what function do echo $username and $password in the bottom do? doesn't defining $username and $password variable as $_POST['username'] enough?

Comment: $password=$_POST['password']; can store the password in variable. and echo $password can print the which can $password stored. nothing else. you can also do the things like. echo $_POST['password'] is equal to echo $password.